# JavaScript: How to Strip out everything and just get the ID?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a Bookmarklet for YouTube, i want to get the ID from the youtube link,

Ex: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgFyi74DVjc

I want only "YgFyi74DVjc" from the above link, that's just an example of what i want, it has to strip out everything and just leave that end part, another thing is
i want to get the ID from this URL as well
http://www.youtube.com/verify_age?next_url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D[YOUTUBEID]

So basically when you click on some video and then on this bookmarklet it gets the youtube video ID and redirects them to a link which unlocks the video or expands the video to full size of the user's browser, i have everything coded and just need a way to get ID's from both the links, i have coded this which works for the 2nd link

```
var url = "http://www.youtube.com/verify_age?next_url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D[YOUTUBEID]";
    var ytcode = url.substr(80,50);
    alert(ytcode);
```

Now i want someway to get ID's from both the links, please help!

Comment: You might want to look into 'regular expressions'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for regex:

```
url.match(/(\?|&)v=([^&]+)/).pop()
```

which, broken down, means:

```
url.match(
    // look for "v=", preceded by either a "?" or a "&",
    // and get the rest of the string until you hit the
    // end or an "&"
    /(\?|&)v=([^&]+)/
)
// that gives you an array like ["?v=YgFyi74DVjc", "?", "YgFyi74DVjc"];
// take the last element
.pop()
```

You can use this for the second form as well if you decode it first:

```
url = decodeURIComponent(url);
```

The `url` variable now equals `"http://www.youtube.com/verify_age?next_url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[YOUTUBEID]"`, and the regex should work.

You could put it all together in a reusable function:

```
function getYouTubeID(url) {
    return decodeURIComponent(url)
        .match(/(\?|&)v=([^&]+)/)
        .pop();
}
```

Comment: @nrabinowitz: indeed, that's why I removed my comment and +1d your answer. Good job.

Comment: @nrabinowitz: that function is really perfect for my bookmarklet and my bookmarklet is working now :D, thanks again, btw is there anyway to + rep or something like that here? sorry but i'm very new here and this is my first question :P

Comment: @Dennis - thanks, glad this worked for you! You may have figured this out by now, but clicking the up arrow above the answer score (top left) gives the answer (and the answerer) +1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ID (i.e. the `v` parameter) is always the last parameter in the URL:

```
url = url.replace("%3D", "=");
var splitUrl = url.split("=");
var yId = splitUrl[splitUrl.length - 1];
```

The `replace` function is used to replace the character code `%3D` with `=`, which is what it represents. You can then split the string on the `=` character, and your ID will be the last element in the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function (just pass it the url and the name of the parameter)

```
function getParameterByName( name, url )

    {
      name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
      var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
      var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
      var results = regex.exec( url );
      if( results == null )
        return "";
      else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    var url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgFyi74DVjc"
    var v= getParameterByName('v', url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification to nrabinowitz answer to allow for YouTube share URLs such as:

http://youtu.be/3Ah8EwyeUho

Also i have attached it to a class so it can be easily reused.

```
$(function(){
    $('.js-youtube').on('blur', function(){
        var newval = '';
        if (newval = $(this).val().match(/(\?|&)v=([^&#]+)/)) {
            $(this).val(newval.pop());
        } else if (newval = $(this).val().match(/(youtu\.be\/)+([^\/]+)/)) {
            $(this).val(newval.pop());
        }
    });
});
```